# Scheffe's theorem

Tags: measure-theory

Scheffe's theorem states that consider the real line $\mathbb{R}$ and sequence of probability densities $\{f_n\}$ such that $f_n \to f$ pointwise. Then if $\{P_n\}$ and $P$ denote the reps. measures on real line, then $P_n \to P$.

My question is hat since we anyways are dealing with density functions (means that the corresponding measures do not have any set of discontinuity), so isn't this just the strong convergence of measures? (why do people mention it as weak convergence?)